# Image of archimedean place of a number field in $\mathbb C$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields and let $\phi$ be an embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb C$. Let $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ be two embeddings $L\to \mathbb C$ which extend $\phi$.

> Then do we have $\psi_1(L)=\psi_2(L)\subset \mathbb C?$

Does this follow from $L/K$ being a normal extension?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$ with a fixed embedding $\phi:K\rightarrow\Bbb C$. If $K\subset L$ is a field extension, a $K$-embedding $\psi:L\rightarrow\Bbb C$ is an embedding such that $\psi_{|K}=\phi$.

If $L/K$ is Galois, all $K$-embeddings $\psi:L\rightarrow\Bbb C$ have the same image.

Indeed there are $n=[L:K]$ such embeddings and also $n={\rm Gal}(L/K)$. Thus, if $\psi$ is any fixed $K$-embedding the $n$ $K$-embeddings
$$
L\stackrel{\sigma}\longrightarrow L\stackrel{\psi}\longrightarrow\Bbb C
$$
for all $\sigma\in{\rm Gal}(L/K)$ exhaust all of possibilities (and they have obviously the same image).

Comment: What happens if $\phi$ is not the identity map on $K$ so that $\psi$ is not a $K$-embedding? Regards

Comment: @Gwan It's the same either way. Sometimes people might even think of $K$ as an abstract field in which case id mapping does not even make sense.

Comment: @Asvin So would the same argument as above work even if $\phi$ is not id? Regards

Comment: @Gwan: I edited my answer. Hope the situation is more clear now. If you like to think of $K$ as a subfield of $\Bbb C$ (this is **not** necessary, and in some instances even misleading) you may take $\phi={\rm id}_K$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes. Any $z\in\psi_1(L)$ is the image of some element $\alpha_1$ algebraic over $K$. Since (by normality) all conjugates $\alpha_k$ of $\alpha_1$ are also in $L$, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ can map these to $\mathbb C$ at most in a different permutation, so at any rate $z=\psi_2(\alpha_k)\in\psi_2(L)$ for some $k$.

Comment: So are you saying that the images of the set of conjugates of $\alpha_1$ under $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are the same? Why is this true? Regards